# Can't seem to select an option in the dropdow using cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I am trying to select "small" from the "Select your size" drop down from the following site using cypress:

*https://www.giant-bicycles.com/us/tcr-advanced-2-pro-compact-2021*

and for the life of me I can't seem to get it. I've used a couple of ways and keep on running into a wall using cypress.

this is what I have so far:

```
/// <reference types="cypress"/>

describe('Giant Website', () => {

    beforeEach('Navigate to Giant website', () =>{
        cy.NavigateToGiantWebsite()
    })

    it('check stock', () => {
       cy.contains('button', 'I Understand').click()
       cy.get('[id="682"]').contains('a', 'TCR Advanced').click()
       cy.get('[alt="TCR Advanced 2 Pro Compact Unicorn White"]').click()
       cy.get('[title="Select your size"]').click({force: true})
       //cy.contains('li', 'Small ').click() this select x-small instead of small
       cy.get('[ng-show="lockedCart.length == 0"]').contains('[for="sizes"]').click() 
        
    });
})
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

The reason(s) that `cy.contains('li', 'Small ')` picks up the x-small size are

- `cy.contains(selector, content)` where content is a **string** will look for the any option containing the specified string, so will match both `x-small` and `small`.
- it returns only one element, and the first one is `x-small`.

Instead of a string you can use a simple **RegExp** and use the caret `^` to restrict it to match at the start.

So, this works

```
cy.contains('li', /^Small/).click()
```

Ref: [.contains() - Regular Expression](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Regular-Expression)

Note, if you use the count of li (e.g `.eq(5)`), your test will need to be updated if website changes options.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below and this is working for me and selecting "Small " from `Select your size` drop down. You could use `eq(5)` option to get into the correct `li` element and use `contains()`

```
cy.get('.dropdown-menu > div > ul li').eq(5).then(($li)=>{
     cy.wrap($li).find('a').find('span').contains("Small ").click();
 })
```

[image]